# How to handle default path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using React Router for my website and I encountered following problem. I have defined my main App component as follows:

```
import './App.css'
import { Navbar } from './Navbar'
import { Outlet } from 'react-router'

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Outlet />
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

and then I used this component for base route:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<App />} >
            <Route path='home' element={<Home />} index />
            <Route path='about' element={<About />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/Home" replace />} />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Everything works well, I can navigate home and about pages, but when I navigate to `/`, it get blank page with `Navbar`, which is understandable, but I don't know how I could display my default home page. Can I somehow instruct React to redirect to `home` ? I cannot set `Home` component for `/`  route, as it would totally break the app (as `App` component has the `Outlet` component).

Libraries' versions:

```
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",  
"react-router": "^6.21.1",  
"react-router-dom": "^6.21.1",
```

Comment: A simpler solution would be to remove the `path` prop from the layout route, e.g. it's pathless, and render the `Home` component on `path="/"`, or keep it and remove the `path="/home"` on the `Home` component so it's rendered as the index route. Just don't try to use both the `path` and `index` props at the same time on the same route, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you already know what causes the problem, just need a guidance with the redirect part.

As you already mentioned, the code is working as intended. Looking at your structure, there are no children configured to be rendered when the path "/" is matched. To fix this, you have to use both `index` attribute *and* trigger a navigation to `"/home"` when path `"/"` is accessed.

To do this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<App />} >
        <Route index element={<Navigate replace to="/home" />} />
        <Route path='home' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='about' element={<About />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/home" />} />
</Routes>
```

Notice the line I added:

```
 <Route index element={<Navigate replace to="/home" />} />
```

This new route has `index` attribute, and also uses `<Navigate>` component provided by react-router.

1. `index` attribute: This attribute makes this route the default route for the parent, which is "/" in your case.
2. `<Navigate>`: Here in your example, we can't render `<Home>` directly, as you specifically requested not to do so:

   > I cannot set `Home` component for `/` route, as it would totally break the app (as `App` component has the `Outlet` component).

   So it will redirect every `"/"` path to `"/home"` instead.

Although this will most probably fix the issue you are facing, I strongly suggest that you use a non-empty `"/"` and do the routing there. In most cases, `"/"` **is** the home, rather than `"/home"`.